# How can I prove that if a relation is symmetric then its inverse is also symmetric?

Tags: relations

> Prove that if $R$ is symmetric, then $R^{-1}$ is symmetric, $R$ being
>   a relation over $A$, and $\lnot(A = \varnothing)$.

This came as an exercise in my book.

I couldn't do anything - there is no (evident) explanation about how to prove things like that in my book (actually it seemed like a bonus question). Some Google searches like *"prove if a relation is symmetric then the inverse is symmetric"* seem to return other topics.

All I could do (nothing) was begin with:

Our hypothesis is $\forall a,b \in A [aRb \implies bRa]$. We want to show, based on it, that $a,b\in A[aR^{-1}b \implies aR^{-1}b]$... and I'm stuck.

Note that, I don't really want the solution to this exercise. I just want an explanation of a "general procedure" I should be taking when working with this *kind* of exercises, as in, "observe that you can do this and that to reach this, etc".

What do I mean by this *"kind"* of exercises? Well, like these:

- If $R$ is antisymmetric, then $R^{-1}$ is antisymmetric.
- If $R$ is reflexive, then $R \cap R^{-1}$ is reflexive.
- If $R$ is transitive, then $R \cap R^{-1}$ is transitive.
- Etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the definition of $R^{-1}$

$aRb \implies bR^{-1}a$

If by symmetry of $R$ you know that $aRb \implies bRa$, what does $bRa$ imply about $R^{-1}$?

Comment: Hm..., so I could do something like... $$(aRb \implies bRa) \implies (bR^{-1}a \implies aR^{-1}b)$$ and then... I'm done since this proves that $R^{-1}$ is symmetric?

Comment: I do believe so. Not too bad, huh?

Comment: Well that was silly... thanks a lot! I guess the other exercises are similar to this.

Comment: Indeed. Out of curiosity, what book are you working from?

Comment: Well, it is in spanish, "Introduction to Discrete Mathematics" ("Introduccion a la Matematica Discreta") by Manuel Murillo Tsiji

Comment: ... I'm not gonna lie - I *am* having trouble with *"If $R$ is transitive, then $R \cap R^{-1}$ is transitive."* - Not very sure how to work with this $\cap$... Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing they want you to think of relations as being ordered pairs: if $aRb$ then $(a,b) \in R$. Likewise if $aR^{-1}b$ then $(a,b) \in R^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo which may be preventing you from solving the problem.  Instead of $a,b\in A[aR^{-1}b \implies aR^{-1}b]$ you want $a,b\in A[aR^{-1}b \implies bR^{-1}a]$  Now imagine you are given $c,d$ such that $cRd$.  Now you know that $dRc$ because of symmetry.  What does that tell you about $R^{-1}?$  What is your definition of $R^{-1}?$